# Hammer.js event on dynamically added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

I had this code for double taps:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').scrollTop(50);

    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('snap_img');

    [].slice.call(elements).forEach(function(element) {
        var hammertime = new Hammer(element),
        img_src = element.getAttribute('src');
        hammertime.on('doubletap', function(event) {
            $(element).next().hide().fadeIn().delay(250).fadeOut();
        });
    });
});
```

But since the double tapped element (.snap_img) is created dynamically by an AJAX call, I need to use event delegation, because when I double tap the snap_img elements now, the event isn't fired.

With the Hammer JQuery plugin, I'm trying to get this to work:

```
// define options and event handlers in an outer scope
    // this avoids re-defining the event handler for every <img> you create

    var snapImgOptions = {
        enable: true;
    };

    var snapImgEvents = {
        doubletap: function () {
            $(this).next().hide().fadeIn().delay(250).fadeOut();
        }
    };

    function createSnapImgs(data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            $('<img class="snap_img">', {src: item}).appendTo("body")
            .hammer(snapImgOptions).on(snapImgEvents);
        });
    }

    // later, your Ajax call...
    $.post( "http://localhost/snapll_back/snap/me_snaps.php?id="+url_user_id,
    function(info) {        
        if(info != "Something went wrong. ERROR{1_RAI_ERROR}" || info != "index.html") {
            $("#snaps").html(info);
        }
        else {
            $('#warning').html(info).fadeIn(200);
        }
    }).done(createSnapImgs);
    return false;
```

This doesn't do anything at all and I don't know why. User @Tomalak gave me this code and I'm sure there's only some small things I need to change now, but I just can't see what exactly I need to do.

Comment: http://hammerjs.github.io/jquery-plugin/ - It's right there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an official [jQuery plugin](http://hammerjs.github.io/jquery-plugin/) that does what you need.

```
// define options and event handlers in an outer scope
// this avoids re-defining the event handler for every <img> you create

var snapImgOptions = {
        enable: true;
    };

var snapImgEvents = {
    doubletap: function () {
        $(this).next().hide().fadeIn().delay(250).fadeOut();          
    }
};

function createSnapImgs(data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        $('<img class="snap_img">', {src: item}).appendTo("body")
        .hammer(snapImgOptions).on(snapImgEvents);
    });
}

// later, your Ajax call...
$.get("/url/of/the/imageData").done(createSnapImgs);
```

The main difference is that this code initializes Hammer not before, but after the Ajax call (i.e. in the success callback).

Comment: I guess this answer sends me to the right direction, but using this code doesn't do what it should do. Nothing happens when I double tap...

Comment: I've done the AJAX call at the end of your code, but for some reason, everything gets messed up when I do that.

Comment: Well without seeing what you did it's impossible to point out where it goes wrong. Set up a jsFiddle that reproduces the problem.